# Change value of an HTML element with scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am trying to scrape data from this website: [Website link](http://www.et.gr/idocs-nph/search/dailyFekForm.html).

I want to download all the PDF files from specific dates.

While I've managed to get the files from the first page and download them correctly, I cannot change the date so I can go back in previous dates and get the old PDFs too.

I have tried this line:

`scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,formxpath='//table//td//input[@type="text"]', formdata={'value': "20.05.2017"}, clickdata={'type':'submit'}, method='POST')`

In the scrapy shell but the `view(response)` always shows me the current date.

I am not sure that this is correct by any means, I am new to scrapy and I'm trying to figure things out. I think that the method is correct since when I change the date the link does not change, so it should be `POST` and not `GET`. 
 Any ideas on how I can get this to work? 
 I thought the `FormRequest()` would be the best option here but I haven't seen any other examples online and the documentation on scrapy's website did not help me that much, so I tried to study the examples that had Login credentials involved, they all used `FormRequest.from_response()`

PS: I have included a screenshot of the HTML code segment that has to do with the date change.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input field name is "date", not "value":

```
    <form id="dailyFekForm" name="dailyFekForm" action="/idocs-nph/search/dailyFekForm.html" method="post">
        <br>
        <div>

        </div>  
      <div class="non-printable" style="padding-left:20px;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:100%; color:#3399FF;" align="left" >
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="center" style="font-size:100%; color:#3399FF;" ><b>Ημερομηνία Κυκλοφορίας</b></td>
                                <td>
                                    <img title="Επιλέξτε ημερομηνία για ημερήσια κυκλοφορία" border="0" src="/idocs-nph/images/tooltip.gif" >
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table> 
                    </td>
                    <td><input id="date" name="date" type="text" value="29.05.2017"/></td>
                    <td><img src="/idocs-nph/images/admin/calendar.gif" id="triggerDate"/></td>
                    <td><input class="save" type="submit" value="Αναζήτηση" name="search" id="search"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

You can also check what your browser sends using its dev tools: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p46Eq.jpg (check "Form data" at the bottom)

Hence, you can use:

```
scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'date': "19.05.2017"})
```

Sample session using scrapy shell, showing different table rows:

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.et.gr/idocs-nph/search/dailyFekForm.html
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(response.css('table#result_table tr:not(.prop) td b').xpath('normalize-space()').getall())
['ΦΕΚ A 77 - 26.05.2017',
 'ΦΕΚ B 1836 - 25.05.2017',
 'ΦΕΚ B 1837 - 25.05.2017',
 (...)
 'ΦΕΚ Α.Α.Π. 112 - 25.05.2017',
 'ΦΕΚ Α.Α.Π. 113 - 26.05.2017',
 'ΦΕΚ Α.Α.Π. 114 - 26.05.2017',
 'ΦΕΚ Α.Α.Π. 115 - 26.05.2017']
>>> fetch(scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'date': "19.05.2017"}))
2017-05-29 14:42:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://www.et.gr/idocs-nph/search/dailyFekForm.html> (referer: None) ['partial']
>>> pprint(response.css('table#result_table tr:not(.prop) td b').xpath('normalize-space()').getall())
['ΦΕΚ A 72 - 19.05.2017',
 'ΦΕΚ A 73 - 19.05.2017',
 'ΦΕΚ A 74 - 19.05.2017',
 (...)
 'ΦΕΚ Υ.Ο.Δ.Δ. 234 - 18.05.2017',
 'ΦΕΚ Α.Α.Π. 105 - 16.05.2017',
 'ΦΕΚ Α.Α.Π. 108 - 16.05.2017']
>>> fetch(scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'date': "16.05.2017"}))
2017-05-29 14:45:53 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://www.et.gr/idocs-nph/search/dailyFekForm.html> (referer: None) ['partial']
>>> pprint(response.css('table#result_table tr:not(.prop) td b').xpath('normalize-space()').getall())
['ΦΕΚ A 69 - 16.05.2017',
 'ΦΕΚ B 1638 - 15.05.2017',
 'ΦΕΚ B 1639 - 15.05.2017',
 (...)
 'ΦΕΚ Υ.Ο.Δ.Δ. 228 - 16.05.2017',
 'ΦΕΚ Υ.Ο.Δ.Δ. 229 - 16.05.2017',
 'ΦΕΚ Α.Α.Π. 102 - 15.05.2017']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Does this work for you? I've tried in Scrapy shell and when I use the view(response) it returns me the same date. Shouldn't I be seeing the changed one?

Comment: Wasn't using fetch.. I feel like an idiot, I've been looking for this error for 3 days now. Thank you so much, really appreciate it.